# Environment and reusable workflow in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I would like to find a way to move the environment: statement from the reusable workflow to the calling workflow.
The begin of the reusable workflow is:

```
name: Reusable Terraform Action
on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      working-folder:
        description: The name of the client folder to process
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  Terraform:
    ***environment: Development***    
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-folder }}
```

and the calling workflow is:

```
name: Deployment TF Reuse
on:  
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  walm:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reuse-terraform.yml
    with:
      working-folder: r3us-walm
```

No matter where I try to place the environment: Development line in the calling workflow, it fails the parsing steps.

I don't mind passing the 4 secrets as parameters to the reusable workflow if I can find a way to obtain them there like this but it still complains about the "uses:" statement.

```
name: Deployment TF Reuse
on:  
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  walm:
    environment: Development
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reuse-terraform.yml
    with:
      working-folder: r3us-walm
      secrets:
        ACID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
        ACS: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        ATID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
        ASID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
```

Comment: Regarding secrets, you may implicitly pass them with `secrets: inherit`. See [Passing inputs and secrets to a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow) for more details.

Comment: The above reusable workflow looks fine if you remove those asterisks around `environment` section and add `steps` to it. What is the parsing error that you're getting? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Azeem, thank you for answering. The stars around the environment section were my attempt to highlight the line which GitHub action is complaining about. Action thinks it doesn't belong there because it complains about the following uses: line. The reason I want the environment there is because I want to run the reusable workflow under the environment: Development context and from another workflow, I want to use the same reusable workflow under the environment: UAT context.

Comment: I got it to work due to an excellent post by Colin's ALM Corner:
https://colinsalmcorner.com/consuming-environment-secrets-in-reusable-workflows/ 
Again, thank you Azeem!

Comment: Good to hear that. Sure thing. So, what was the exact issue? If you could self-answer this with details, that'd be helpful for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of this wonderful [article](https://colinsalmcorner.com/consuming-environment-secrets-in-reusable-workflows) and ideas from [Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem), I managed to get it working.

Here is my simple calling/caller workflow:

```yaml
name: Calling Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy_dev:
    name: Deploy to Dev
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reuse.yml
    with:
      environment: Development
    secrets:
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
      
  deploy_prod:
    name: Deploy to Prod
    needs: deploy_dev
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reuse.yml
    with:
      environment: UAT
    secrets:
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

and, the called reusable workflow is:

```yaml
name: Called Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: string
        description: environment to deploy to
        required: true
    secrets:
      PASSWORD:
        required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to ${{ inputs.environment }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    
    steps:
    - name: Dump Password
      run: |
        echo Password is $PASSWORD
        if [[ $PASSWORD == *"password"* ]]; then
          echo "This is the UAT password!"
        else
          echo "This is NOT the UAT password!"
        fi
      env:
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

In addition to learning about passing the environment as a parameter, I was reminded that simple little workflows are best for checking approaches.

Thanks!